# How to allow only string in input text field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, dom-events, haml

How to allow only string input on text_field using rails haml form.

```
.field
  = f.label "agent_name"
  = f.text_field :agent_name, :required => true,:id=>"agent_name_validation"
```

```
  $("#agent_name_validation").keypress(function(event) {
    var string = /^[a-z]+$/i;
    if(event.which != string){
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this script

```
$("#agent_name_validation").keypress(function(event){
   var inputValue = event.charCode;
   if(!(inputValue >= 65 && inputValue <= 120) && (inputValue != 32 && inputValue != 0)){
       event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following Jquery function to remove number from text field

```
$("#agent_name_validation").keyup(function(e) {
  // Our regex
  // a-z => allow all lowercase alphabets
  // A-Z => allow all uppercase alphabets
  var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
  // This is will test the value against the regex
  // Will return True if regex satisfied
  if (regex.test(this.value) !== true)
  //alert if not true
  //alert("Invalid Input");

  // You can replace the invalid characters by:
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/, '');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RegExp.prototype​.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to remove the entered character if that is not a string in between the [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `[a-z]`:

Notice that this will check only lowercase characters:

```js
$('#agent_name_validation').on('input', function () {
  if (!/[a-z]$/.test(this.value)) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, -1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="agent_name_validation" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add jQuery validation gem
https://github.com/meowsus/jquery-validation-rails
Too much easy way to put lots of validation 
All validation is their ready to use, you have to just use 
Their ready methods

myField: { lettersonly: true }

And it’s done..
Best of luck..

Answer (score 0):

@Suman Das

Try this code,To allow only string in input text field:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Javascript Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>

      <form action="/data.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="fullName" onkeypress="return (event.charCode > 64 && 
        event.charCode < 91) || (event.charCode > 96 && event.charCode < 123)" 
        placeholder="Full Name">
        <input type="submit">  
      </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I hope above code will be useful for you.

Thank you.